# What are active_record instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Company model in my rails application. Which consists of following fields:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  include Validatable
  validates :contact_one, :city, :state, :country, :address, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_many :company_domains
  has_many :domains, through: :company_domains
  has_many :job_posts
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  belongs_to :industry, optional: true, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true

  def pending_approval?
    self.status == 'in-review'
  end

  def approved?
    self.status == 'approved'
  end

end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: companies
#
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  address               :string
#  city                  :string
#  company_domains_count :integer
#  company_size          :string
#  contact_one           :string
#  contact_two           :string
#  contacts_count        :integer
#  country               :string
#  cover_image           :string
#  email                 :string
#  facebook_url          :string
#  fax                   :string
#  google_plus_url       :string
#  job_posts_count       :integer
#  latitude              :float
#  linkedin_url          :string
#  logo_image            :string
#  longitude             :float
#  name                  :string
#  state                 :string
#  status                :string
#  twitter_url           :string
#  website               :string
#  year_of_establishment :date
#  youtube_url           :string
#  created_at            :datetime         not null
#  updated_at            :datetime         not null
#  industry_id           :integer
#  user_id               :integer
```

When I check **Company.instance_methods(false)** into rails console Then i got following array of instance methods:

```
[:after_add_for_images?, :after_add_for_images=, :before_remove_for_images, :before_remove_for_images?, :before_remove_for_images=, :after_remove_for_images, :after_remove_for_images?, :after_remove_for_images=, :belongs_to_counter_cache_after_update, :autosave_associated_records_for_industry, :autosave_associated_records_for_user, :autosave_associated_records_for_company_domains, :validate_associated_records_for_company_domains, :before_add_for_company_domains, :before_add_for_company_domains?, :before_add_for_company_domains=, :after_add_for_company_domains, :after_add_for_company_domains?, :after_add_for_company_domains=, :before_remove_for_company_domains, :before_remove_for_company_domains?, :before_remove_for_company_domains=, :after_remove_for_company_domains, :after_remove_for_company_domains?, :after_remove_for_company_domains=, :autosave_associated_records_for_domains, :validate_associated_records_for_domains, :before_add_for_domains, :before_add_for_domains?, :before_add_for_domains=, :after_add_for_domains, :after_add_for_domains?, :after_add_for_domains=, :before_remove_for_domains, :before_remove_for_domains?, :before_remove_for_domains=, :after_remove_for_domains, :after_remove_for_domains?, :after_remove_for_domains=, :autosave_associated_records_for_job_posts, :validate_associated_records_for_job_posts, :before_add_for_job_posts, :before_add_for_job_posts?, :before_add_for_job_posts=, :after_add_for_job_posts, :after_add_for_job_posts?, :after_add_for_job_posts=, :before_remove_for_job_posts, :before_remove_for_job_posts?, :before_remove_for_job_posts=, :after_remove_for_job_posts, :after_remove_for_job_posts?, :after_remove_for_job_posts=, :autosave_associated_records_for_contacts, :validate_associated_records_for_contacts, :before_add_for_contacts, :before_add_for_contacts?, :before_add_for_contacts=, :after_add_for_contacts, :after_add_for_contacts?, :after_add_for_contacts=, :before_remove_for_contacts, :before_remove_for_contacts?, :before_remove_for_contacts=, :after_remove_for_contacts, :after_remove_for_contacts?, :after_remove_for_contacts=, :autosave_associated_records_for_images, :validate_associated_records_for_images, :before_add_for_images, :before_add_for_images?, :before_add_for_images=, :after_add_for_images]
```

Can anyone please help me to understand what these methods will do?

Comment: This would be too broad for a SO answer. But to set you on the path - a lot of them are internals and/or things you wouldn't really need to call. If you want to understand a given method see if the method name includes something varying and replace that varying thingy with nothing. For example, in `validate_associated_records_for_company_domains`, `company_domains` would be variable as it's the name of a `has_many` association. Then google the new name you got.

Comment: I highly recommend reading about [Active Record Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html), [Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), [Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html), [Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and the [Query Interface](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are associations callbacks from

> Association Callbacks Normal callbacks hook into the life cycle of
>   Active Record objects, allowing you to work with those objects at
>   various points. For example, you can use a :before_save callback to
>   cause something to happen just before an object is saved.
>
> Association callbacks are similar to normal callbacks, but they are
>   triggered by events in the life cycle of a collection. There are four
>   available association callbacks:
>
> before_add after_add before_remove after_remove

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7ed1302cd2c458bb552fcd0ded83403c039de28d/guides/source/association_basics.md#association-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you're using some sort of gem for handling image uploads? Looks like these are hooks for the image uploads so you can perform actions before/after adding/removing images. this would before similar to the active record hooks like before_save etc

I would refer to the documentation of the gem you are using.